# ConcurrentDictionary, Store Key and Compression

Tags: c#, hash-map, serialization, compression

So i have a  `ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>`

The "int" is merely the way i store the key, which i want more recommendations on.

Currently i do like this.

```
        public string memoize(Func<string, uint, string> functor, string code, uint id)
    {
        //Used for the lookup to identify if it's been inputed before
        int codeHash = code.GetHashCode();
        string functor_return;


        if (_compilerCache.TryGetValue(codeHash, out functor_return))
            return functor_return;


        functor_return = functor?.Invoke(code, id);
        _compilerCache[codeHash] = functor_return;

        return functor_return;
    }
```

Why do i use GetHashCode()?
I don't know, it's just the only way i could figure out rather than store the string value itself.

I also save this "Cache", and hence why the compression and key is important.

```
    //Serialize and Compress object to file
    public static void SerializeObject<T>(string filename, T obj)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        using (var cStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(cStream, obj);
        }
    }

    //DeSerialize and Decompress object from file
    public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string filename)
    {
        T objectToBeDeSerialized = default(T);
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            using (var cStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                objectToBeDeSerialized = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(cStream);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + " : Error DeSerializing Cache, corrupted?");
        }

        return objectToBeDeSerialized;
    }
```

It all works, but i would like to improve it.
I don't really know if even GetHashCode is a good way to do this thing,
i just took it randomly as before i just stored the value itself.

The values are usually around 10-20 characters i guess, usually very similar (which should be compression friendly i guess).

So can anything be done to improve this?

Comment: Have you experienced any memory or performance issues or why are you trying to optimize it to the last bit? About how many items do we speak? A thousand or tens of millions or more?

Comment: some hundredthousands probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetHashCode` is used internally by `ConcurrentDictionary` to speed up access to the real key.

But, there is no guarantee that 2 different strings will return 2 different HashCode, you may encounter collisions! Such collisions are handled by the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

So with your code, as the `_compilerCache` is a `Dictionary<int,functor>` (it seems to be) and not a `Dictionary<string,functor>`, you may encounter rare events where two different codes will give the same key. If such a collision happends, you have a subtle and rare bug.

I suggest the following :

- stick to a `Dictionary<string,functor>`, use the real key
- don't input a HashCode instead of the real key
- you may also input your own `GetHashCode` in Dictionary constructor

Using code instead of int as a key has a price : memory footprint is larger, but with small strings (10-20 char), it should not be an issue.

Hope this helps !

Comment: What do you mean using code instead of int as a key?
Why i use int was simply cause of the "key" right?

The thing i want to memioze returns a String and inputs a String.
So basically "string conversion" if you like.

Feels like i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't so clear in my answer. What I means by code was from your code => string code

Comment: So i should just use my input string as the key?

Comment: That was the idea : your input string should be the real key, the GetHashCode function may cause collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a few comments.

Instead of using the type `Func<string, uint, string>`, consider defining a delegate type. This will allow you to give a name to this type as well as its parameters.

For your `SerializeObject` and `DeSerializeObject` methods:

The method names `SerializeObject` and `DeSerializeObject` are fine, but they don't tell me that they use the filesystem or data compression. If you wanted to make this fact clear, you could name the methods `CompressObjectToFile` and `DecompressObjectFromFile`.

When writing the word "deserialize" in title case, write it as "Deserialize", with a lowercase S, not as "DeSerialize", with an uppercase S. The word "deserialize" is only a single word, after all.

Consider not doing any exception handling in the `DeSerializeObject`. The problem with doing exception handling there is that if I'm calling `DeSerializeObject`, I'm not given any choice about how I want to handle errors. If you remove the exception handling, then I can handle the errors however I want.